# Python: Making hangman. Trouble with strings

Tags: python, string

I am making a game called hangman. I used a for loop to make it test whether there are any of that letter in the secret word then print at the top the letter/letters that was right where it is/they are in the word. For example if the secret word was "button" and you guessed "t", it would print " _ _ t t _ _ " and if the secret word was "cat" and you guessed "a", it would print "_ a _". I want it to be able to print where both the letters are in 1 line, but it prints out multiple lines: " _ _ t _ _ _ " and on the second line the same thing. I know why it prints multiple lines. I've looked over it a bit. But I need to know how to print it all on 1 line like the first "button word example". It also prints the wrong amount of " _"s. And it never gives a winning/loosing message - I suspect this is because it probably can't get out of the while loop?

Anyway, help is appreciated and if you can give any programming tips and ways to tidy/make my code better please do.  Here is the code; I don't know whether this is enough info for anyone to give help so if you need more please ask.

```
import random

file = open('LIST_OF_WORDS.txt', 'r')
word_list = file.readlines()
file.close()

alphabet = "A B C D E F G \nH I J K L M N \nO P Q R S T U \nV W X Y Z"


alphabet_dict = {"A":0, "B":2, "C":4, "D":6,"E":8,"F":10,"G":12,"H":15, \
               "I":17, "J":19, "K":21, "L":23,"M":25,"N":27,"O":30,"P":32, \
               "Q":34, "R":36, "S":38, "T":40,"U":42,"V":45,"W":47,"X":49, \
               "Y":51, "Z":53}

MAN_NOTHING = "\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n"

MAN_HEAD = \
r"""
        _
       /-\
       \_/








"""

MAN_BODY = \
r"""
        _
       /-\
       \_/
      /\Y/\
      | : |
      | : |





"""

MAN_LEFT_ARM = \
r"""
        _
       /-\
       \_/
      /\Y/\
     || : |
     || : |
     (




"""

MAN_RIGHT_ARM = \
r"""
        _
       /-\
       \_/
      /\Y/\ ;-,
     || : |\//
     || : |\/
     (



"""

MAN_LEGS = \
r"""
        _
       /-\
       \_/
      /\Y/\ ;-,
     || : |\//
     || : |\/
     (|---|
      | | |
      | | |
      |_|_|

"""      

MAN_COMPLETE = \
r"""
        _
       /-\
       \_/
      /\Y/\ ;-,
     || : |\//
     || : |\/
     (|---|
      | | |
      | | |
      |_|_|
      (/ \)
"""      

def man_state(state=0):
    if state == 0:
        return MAN_NOTHING
    elif state == 1:
        return MAN_HEAD    
    elif state == 2:
        return MAN_BODY
    elif state == 3:
        return MAN_LEFT_ARM
    elif state == 4:
        return MAN_RIGHT_ARM
    elif state == 5:
        return MAN_LEGS
    elif state == 6:
        return MAN_COMPLETE

def hangman():
    num_letters_wrong = 0
    num_letters_correct = 0
    fin = False
    secret_word = random.choice(word_list)
    word_correct = None
    word_length = len(secret_word)
    letter_complete_status = list(" _" * word_length)
    while fin == False:
        print("The word was " + secret_word) #test
        print(man_state(state=num_letters_wrong))
        print(alphabet)
        letter_guess = input("\nGuess a letter: ")
        if letter_guess not in secret_word:
            if num_letters_wrong == 7:
                fin == True
                word_correct = False
            elif num_letters_wrong < 7:
                num_letters_wrong += 1
                print("".join(letter_complete_status))
            else:
                print("Error? - PLEASE! Report this to William/gogobebe2!! Thankyou :)")
        elif letter_guess in secret_word:
            num_letters_correct += 1
            if num_letters_correct >= word_length:
                fin == True
                word_correct = True
            for l in secret_word:
                if letter_guess == l:   
                    letter_complete_status[secret_word.index(l) + 1] = l
                    print("".join(letter_complete_status))
    print("The word was " + secret_word)
    if word_correct == True:
        print("Welldone, you guessed correctly")
    elif word_correct == False:
        print("Gameover! You loose!!")
        hangman()


#If the file is the main file then start the program    
if __name__ == '__main__':
    hangman()
```

I should also point out I am running on Linux.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I run the program, it seems to track guesses okay, and prints the known letters on one line:

```
Guess a letter: s
 _ is_ _ _
The word was this
```

It prints a little strange as you insert spaces when generating `letter_complete_status`

```
letter_complete_status = list(" _" * word_length)
```

However when you overwrite the values, you only add 1 to the index

```
letter_complete_status[secret_word.index(l) + 1] = l
```

When you should be multiplying by 2 also

```
letter_complete_status[secret_word.index(l)*2 + 1] = l
```

I also had to strip the extra trailing newline off your word list

```
file = open('LIST_OF_WORDS.txt', 'r')
word_list = [l.strip() for l in file]
```

Your "win" condition is incorrect for words that have the same letter more than once

```
num_letters_correct += 1
if num_letters_correct >= word_length: # doesn't work for eg 'hello'
```

Lastly, your exit condition is never satisfied as you are not assigning the value of `fin` correctly

```
fin == True # double equals means this is just a comparison
```

It should be just

```
fin = True
```

Comment: @gogobebe2 strip removes whitespace from the ends of a string http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.strip in this case it removes the new-line character from the end of each line

Comment: @gogobebe2 yes, putting it in the for loop instead should help. If you found this answer helpful, please mark it as the accepted answer :)

Answer (score 1):

```
temp_word = 'correct'
letters_guessed = ['g','r','a','b']

for letter in temp_word:
    if letter not in letters_guessed:
        temp_word = temp_word.replace(letter,'_')

print temp_word

## >>> '__rr___'
## string.replace(old, new) you can use any character for new '*' returns '**rr***'
```